# How to apply a update after an inser or update POSTGRESQL Trigger

Tags: postgresql, triggers, sql-update

How to apply an update after an insert or update in `POSTGRESQL;` I have got a table which has a field `lastupdate;` I want that field to be set up whenever the row is updated or when it was inserted. 
I tried this trigger, but It is not working! HELP!!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_update_profile() 
                             RETURNS TRIGGER AS $update_profile$
    BEGIN
    IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT' OR TG_OP = 'UPDATE' ) THEN
           UPDATE profile SET lastupdate=now() where oid=OLD.oid;
           RETURN NULL;
     ELSEIF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
       RETURN NULL;
        END IF;
    RETURN NULL; -- result is ignored since this is an AFTER trigger
    END;
$update_profile$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: What you want to do is much the same as an example given in the manual. Did you take a look at the docs on pl/pgsql triggers?

Comment: yes, but I just realise my trigger is recursive, that's why it was not working.

Comment: ... which is why the manual shows use of a BEFORE trigger that modifies NEW instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your trigger function can be a lot easier than you had. Keep in mind that PG will do the update or the insert on the original table, you only have to deal with keeping the `profile` table up-to-date:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_update_profile() 
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $update_profile$
BEGIN
  UPDATE profile SET lastupdate = now() WHERE oid = NEW.oid;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$update_profile$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The `INSERT` and `UPDATE` trigger functions both use the `NEW` parameter; the `INSERT` trigger function does not have the `OLD` parameter. You should always return `NEW` from the trigger function if successful (or `OLD` from a `DELETE` trigger), even if it is an `AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE` trigger; the whole operation will be rolled back if `NULL` is returned. If you then define the actual trigger to fire after the insert or update, you should be good:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_update_profile
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON my_table
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE fn_update_profile();
```

Comment: Actually, it is not working, I dont know the reason, Im getting the following errors: ERROR:  límite de profundidad de stack alcanzado
HINT:  Incremente el parámetro de configuración «max_stack_depth» (actualmente 2048kB), después de asegurarse que el límite de profundidad de stack de la plataforma es adecuado.
CONTEXT:  sentencia SQL: «UPDATE profile SET lastupdate = now() WHERE oid = NEW.oid»
función PL/pgSQL fn_update_profile() en la línea 3 en sentencia SQL
sentencia SQL: «UPDATE profile SET lastupdate = now() WHERE oid = NEW.oid»

Comment: It appears that your `profile` table is associated with the trigger function and so you get recursion and eventually a stack overflow. If this is the case, you should make this a `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE` trigger and simply set `NEW.lastupdate := now()` and then `RETURN NEW`.